# How to assign unique id to checkboxes which correspond to its row number (update: or item ID) under Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm designing a table to display transaction history for baby items for a javascript course. How to assign each checkbox with unique id composed of number sequence corresponding to row number?

The wireframe is shown below.

[image: A design of the table]

Each row is numbered in sequence, starting from 1 to the end of the table row.

In the rightmost column, with the help of Bootstrap 4, I put a toggle checkbox, so that the user can manually choose whether to list his / her item for sale ('listing') or end the sales ('ended').

I've been told that each checkbox id has to be unique, so I intend to name the input-id of each one 'toogle1', 'toogle2', etc, according to their respective row number.

My question is: how to auto-generate the id number?

I did a similar exercise for the row number, with the following code:

HTML:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="800" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="seq-number" data-width="100" data-width-unit="px">Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

for (var i = 1, rowlength = rows.length; i < rowlength; i++) {rows[i].children[0][text]= i;
}
```

On the other hand, my code for the table and checkbox is as follows:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="800" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="status" data-width="200" data-width-unit="px">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>



<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" data-width="100">
            <script>
                 $(function () {
                 $('#toggle1').bootstrapToggle({
                 on: 'Listing',
                 off: 'Ended'
                 });
                 })
            </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I expect the input id (ie. toggle1, toggle2,..., toggle999) can be generated and assigned automatically, corresponding to the row number.

I expect the end result with id = "'toggle' + i".

Thank you very much for your help.

**Update: @cengiz sevimli reminds me that it might better to assign status checkbox id with item ID, since it is 'more unique' than row numbers. But how to create the id, say a product of user id #000001 with timestamp - 000001-201910301600, for example?**

Comment: You could use class rather than the Id because It would be easy to add bootstrapToggle event for all element those have same class.
Also It would help you to write JS code single time.

Answer (score 1):

Let me say that you don't really need to assign a unique id to any checkbox, you could pick any information you need directly from the html in the selected row.

Anyway, if you would like to have an id for the selected items (just these will be submitted with your form), you could set the id to each input in the table (not the selectAll):

```
$(".cb input").each(
  (index, el) => {
    // If the checkbox is not the "Select All"
    if($(el).attr("name") === "btSelectItem") {
      // Choose an ID
      let newId = $(el).closest("tr").find(".number").text();
      // Set it to the current checkbox
      $(el).prop("id", newId);
    }
  }
)
```

In order to simplify the selection of the checkboxes in your table, you could add a class to the checkbox column (ie: `class="cb"`):

```
<th data-field="cb" data-checkbox="true" class="cb" />
```

So as you can see above, you could attach a listener to the event change to the input under the elements with `class="cb"`.

See the following complete example, please:

```js
var $table = $('#table');
var mydata = 
[
    {
        number: 1,
        id: "Item 1",
        name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        id: "Item 2",
        name: "Name 2"
    },
    {
        number: 3,
        id: "Item 3",
        name: "Name 3"
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('.table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });
    
    $(".cb input").each(
      (index, el) => {
        if($(el).attr("name") === "btSelectItem") {
          let newId = $(el).closest("tr").find(".number").text();
          $(el).prop("id", newId);
        }
      }
    ).change(
      function() {
        let selected = $(this);
        if(selected.attr("name") === "btSelectItem") {
          console.log("Selected: ", selected.prop("id"));
        }
      }
    );

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-field="cb" data-checkbox="true" class="cb" />
              <th data-field="number" class="number">Number</th>
              <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
              <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Using class names is more appropriate in this case. When you create a class in CSS, you can add this class to any HTML tag you want. This way you can increase your code's readablitiy, reusability and flexibility. But if you are asking a code snippet in JS that generates a unique id see the code below:

```
// Generate unique IDs for use as pseudo-private/protected names.
// Similar in concept to
// <http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:names>.
//
// The goals of this function are twofold:
// 
// * Provide a way to generate a string guaranteed to be unique when compared
//   to other strings generated by this function.
// * Make the string complex enough that it is highly unlikely to be
//   accidentally duplicated by hand (this is key if you're using `ID`
//   as a private/protected name on an object).
//
// Use:
//
//     var privateName = ID();
//     var o = { 'public': 'foo' };
//     o[privateName] = 'bar';
var ID = function () {
  // Math.random should be unique because of its seeding algorithm.
  // Convert it to base 36 (numbers + letters), and grab the first 9 characters
  // after the decimal.
  return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
```

source: **gordonbrander**

Comment: I feel doubtful about using class names, as each checkbox should be unique for recording and retrieving transaction record. Also, since each row number has been assigned, it will be useful to linking the checkbox id with row number.

On second thought, a better way for unique identification is combining the "Item ID" with the name of each checkbox. Example: if the item ID is 2019103016000001, then the checkbox id will be "id2019103016000001".

Comment: Do you want random Id's to be generated or assigning Id by yourself?

Comment: It should not be random. Generate with a combination of user ID with timestamp (precision up to minutes).

Comment: You can use     ```var now = new Date();

timestamp = now.getFullYear().toString(); // 2011
timestamp += (now.getFullMonth < 9 ? '0' : '') + now.getFullMonth().toString(); // JS months are 0-based, so +1 and pad with 0's
timestamp += (now.getDate < 10) ? '0' : '') + now.getDate().toString(); // pad with a 0
... etc... with .getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(), getMilliseconds() ```